# how to apply a vectorized operation for specific column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, dtype

let's imagine we have the `titanic` dataset stored in a dataframe and we want to normalize some of its columns. also, imagine we don't have any `Nan` value.

this dataframe consists of numeric and obj columns and we don't want to lose them.

Also, we have numeric columns such as `survived` (boolean actually) and we don't want to change them.
now, what would you do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a very generalizable way to do what you want. Since you're dealing with a relatively small data set, you can probably inspect it with `df.head()`, infer which columns are numerical as opposed to categorical, and select the columns that you want to normalize.

However, if you want a solution that is sort of generalizable but not completely fail-safe, you can select columns that are only `float` type (since all of the integer type columns in the titanic data set such as `PassengerID, Survived, PClass, ...` are categorical). However, this wouldn't necessarily work for other data sets because you could have integer columns that you may still want to normalize (like ages that are rounded to the nearest integer, for example)

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/master/titanic.csv')
cols_numeric = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype.kind == 'f']
```

This returns the columns `['Age', 'Fare']`